# Checking the solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$y'=\frac{x}{y^2+1}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x}{y^2+1}$$

$$(y^2+1)d y={x}dx$$

$$\frac{y^3}{3}+y=\frac{x^2}{2}+C$$

$$y=\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^3}{3}+C$$

To check the solution, I need to take the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$?

Comment: Yes, you are good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, you got an implicit solution.You could solve the 3rd degree equation in $y$ via the Cardano formulas, but more often than not that is not required and practically also not very useful